# Is it possible to find out attached display hardware while connected via RDP?

Tags: windows-10, display, remote-desktop

While connected via RDP `msinfo32` will display the information about the driver responsible for RDP.

[image: Screenshot of msinfo32.exe while connected via RDP]

The Windows display settings are unavailable and - in my case - the nVidia control panel shows nothing either.

So how can I find out the attached display hardware from home office?

Comment: I would suggest opening Device Manager and looking at the Monitors connected there. RDP creates it's own output and so the standard config options don't show the physically attached hardware. Another option is Remote Control, which DOES mirror locally attached hardware.